IncorrectCellLabel: (1, 0) after using d2g.upload()
Any code I tried gives me same error
for example:
df_reset = df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)  
 d2g.upload(df_reset, table_name, sheet_name, credentials=credentials, row_names=False)

Or this
d2g.upload(df,table_name,sheet_name, credentials=credentials,start_cell='A1')

I'm always getting the same error:

IncorrectCellLabel: (1, 0)

How to solve it?
Im trying to upload my df to Google SpreadSheets. My code can make new spreadsheet and worksheet so my Api works correct. But the df data is not loaded into the table cause of error IncorrectCellLabel: (1, 0)/
